# Get all the data with the Youtube API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm creating a fullstack project for a school that have a active Youtube channel. My project is suppose to help maintain and combine videos and information from Youtube into the website.

The problem is - every API request, as noted in the documentation, is limited to 50 units of data at max. This Youtube channel has been going for years, and now i'm stuck without any access to the pre-latest-fifty videos on the channel.

Recommendations anyone?

I hope someone from the youtube team could help me with this issue, or even be provided with an alternative online, instead of hand-scraping or bruteforcing my way to the data

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: It seems that you aren't aware of the [YouTube Data API v3 pagination mechanism](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/pagination).